# Run test on connected device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run an Android instrumentation test on a running emulator, I get

```
09/27 14:37:58: Launching <test name>
Error while waiting for device: AVD Nexus_4_API_25 is already running.
If that is not the case, delete the files at
   /home/aromanov/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_25.avd/*.lock
and try again.
```

I certainly don't want to restart the emulator each time: it takes far too long. And `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` runs without restarting the emulator. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the target device was already set in the test configuration under `General > Deployment Target Options > Target > Emulator`. If I select `Open Select Deployment Target Dialog` instead of `Emulator`, it works (and I can choose `Use same target device for future launches` to avoid choosing it every time).

No idea why this fixes the problem, and I'll be happy to accept any answer which does explain it.